# LoadPercentage win32_processor Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, cpu-usage, win32-process, get-wmiobject

I have written the following code for a Powershell script:

```
while($true){
  $os= Get-Ciminstance Win32_OperatingSystem
  $cpu=Get-WmiObject win32_processor
  $cpuUsage=($cpu.LoadPercentage)

  $os | Select @{Name = "CPU usage"; Expression = {$cpuUsage}},
  @{Name = "FreeGB"; Expression = {[math]::Round($_.FreePhysicalMemory/1mb, 2)}}
}
```

These are a sample from the outputs I'm getting:

- LoadPercentage:2
- LoadPercentage:0
- LoadPercentage:1
- LoadPercentage:
- LoadPercentage:7
- LoadPercentage:10
- LoadPercentage:8
- LoadPercentage:
- LoadPercentage:2

I don't understand why sometimes null values are being generated. Is this a flaw within the function itself or is there something wrong with my code? Has this ever happened to anyone before?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps `Get-WmiObject` fails occasionally because you're retrying too fast? Try adding a delay between the queries (`Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50`).

Comment: Are you sure that error not in `#outputting $cpuUsage value in text file` line? Can you reproduce this with simple line: `for() {(Get-WmiObject win32_processor).LoadPercentage}`?

Comment: @PetSerAl I have added more code as requested :)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers You might be right, I'm going to try this now.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still happened even though I added the delay. I tried with the 50 millisecond delay as well as a 1 second delay and it still happened in both cases (although less often than before I think). @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: I've noticed something strange in the values, as I am also taking a timestamp along with the CPU Percentage Load value, and while all the non-null values have a 1 second delay between them, the null values have a greater than 1 second delay between them. @AnsgarWiechers